# How to combine these two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How would I combine these two arrays:

```
x = np.asarray([[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3], [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3], 
                 [4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3], [5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3]])
y = np.asarray([[0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4], [0.5]])
```

Into something like this:

```
xy = [[0.1, [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3]], [0.2, [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3]...
```

Thank you for the assistance!

Someone suggested I post code that I have tried and I realized I had forgot to:

```
xy = np.array(list(zip(x, y)))
```

This is my current solution, however it is extremely inefficient.

Comment: You forgot to post the code you tried.

Comment: In NumPy, the original two separate arrays will be a lot more convenient and efficient to work with.

Comment: This would be ideal, however I have to randomize both arrays and so need some way to pair them together first.

Comment: No you don't. If you're talking about shuffling them in the same order, you can do that by generating a single random permutation array and applying that permutation to both arrays.

Comment: You could make a (5,2) object dtype array and assign these arrays (with some care).  Or makes (5,) shape structured array, and assign the arrays to fields.  But if all you are doing is shuffling, I agree that it's better to leave them separate.

Comment: If an answer helped you, please accept one. Otherwise please explain what's missing

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine

```
[[a,b] for a,b in zip(y,x)]
```

Out:

```
[[array([0.1]), array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])],
 [array([0.2]), array([2. , 2.1, 2.2, 2.3])],
 [array([0.3]), array([3. , 3.1, 3.2, 3.3])],
 [array([0.4]), array([4. , 4.1, 4.2, 4.3])],
 [array([0.5]), array([5. , 5.1, 5.2, 5.3])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure numpy solution will be much faster than list comprehension for large arrays.

I do have to say your use case makes no sense, as there is no logic in putting these arrays into a single data structure, and I believe you should re check your design.

Like @user2357112 supports Monica was subtly implying, this is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). See if this is *really* what you are trying to solve, and not something else. If you want something else, try asking about *that*.

I strongly suggest checking what you want to do before moving on, as you will put yourself in a place with bad design.

---

That aside, here's a solution

```
import numpy as np


x = np.asarray([[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3], [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3],
                 [4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3], [5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3]])
y = np.asarray([[0.1], [0.2], [0.3], [0.4], [0.5]])


xy = np.hstack([y, x])
print(xy)
```

prints

> ```
> [[0.1 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3]
>  [0.2 2.  2.1 2.2 2.3]
>  [0.3 3.  3.1 3.2 3.3]
>  [0.4 4.  4.1 4.2 4.3]
>  [0.5 5.  5.1 5.2 5.3]]
> ```